# Xcode / plist - run application always in Dark/Light theme on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, plist

There exists a property to make app running always in Dark mode -- [UIUserInterfaceStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiuserinterfacestyle)

[image]

problem is.... it doesn't work on macOS.

I have tried to set

- LIGHT
- Light
- light
- .light
- 1

file changes inside of the file is correct:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

But result is always is the same - It just doesn't work and app runs with system configuration of theme.

> Xcode: Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
>
> MacOS: 10.15.2 (19C57) Catalina
>
> App is based on SwiftUI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for the full on SwiftUI version:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SwiftUI_Football_GridApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().preferredColorScheme(.light)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that UIInterfaceStyle is a UIKit feature. It is for tvOS/iOS. It does nothing on MacOS. You are writing a MacOS app, not an iOS app. Thus your changes to the *Info.plist* naturally have no effect.

The way to opt out of light/dark mode on MacOS is completely different, and is documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_macos_app

Basically you want to use the NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance key (though it would be better just to adopt dark mode compatibility).

Comment: my app is based on SwiftUI. And I want to make a single action to change theme for all windows of the app, so... looks like those documentation is too old for my situation

Comment: What I said still stands. You asked why your Info.plist setting is not working, and I told you why.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

### First Solution

Try uninstall the app from device or the simulator. Make sure you cleaned the project. The right key is **'Light'** indeed, is case sensitive.

Ok, if that's not working you can do other things that achieve the same result.

### Second Solution

Call this code below in `AppDelegates`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

Please, let me know if that work out for you.

Comment: there is written that app is for macOS